# how to override a js file which exist in module in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to override a js file which exist in module.
path - `/website/modules/onepagecheckoutps/views/js/front/onepagecheckoutps.js`

Is their any way we can override this file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If JS is properly loaded in module you can override it by copying file to this path:

/website/themes/your_theme/modules/onepagecheckoutps/views/js/front/onepagecheckoutps.js

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would i make sure which theme is active ?

Comment: i don't have this directory , can i create one & copy file ? will it work ?

Comment: yes, exactly, you need to copy this file to active theme, that's it, how to know which one is active? for example by checking source code of website in browser

Comment: Hello, can you please take a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63451713/504-gateway-time-out-on-updating-order-status-prestashop