# 504 Gateway Time-out on updating order status prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I get timeout when i try to change orderstatus in prestashop not sure what is missing.

```
<?php
$sts_id          = $_POST['status_id'];
$order_box       = $_POST['orderBox'];
$selected_orders = implode(",", $order_box);
$get_orders      = 'SELECT id_order FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'orders` WHERE  id_order in (' . $selected_orders . ') and current_state !=' . $sts_id;
$get_order_id    = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($get_orders);

if (count($get_order_id) > 0) {
    $order_to_convert = array_column($get_order_id, 'id_order');
    foreach ($order_to_convert as $odr_id) {
        $objOrder          = new Order($odr_id);
        $history           = new OrderHistory();
        $history->id_order = (int) $objOrder->id;
        $history->changeIdOrderState($sts_id, (int) ($objOrder->id));
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: how many orders do you have here?

Comment: I need to change order status of 61 orders at a time (on one click)

Comment: I have used above code to do so, but i get time out, i am not sure why. can you please help ?

Comment: Or may be we can use mysql query to update order status just like what the above posted code in question does, your expert opinion ?

Comment: @KrystianPodemski any thoughts ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best approach to optimize php code (loop)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445040/what-is-the-best-approach-to-optimize-php-code-loop)